# Why can't Rstats get or "getAnywhere" find arguments inside a nested function?

Tags: r, meta

Consider these two functions in R:

```
g <- function(){

    get("input")
}

h <- function(input){

    g()
}
```

When calling `h(1:3)`, why can't `g()` find `input`?

Answer (score 0):

The variable `input`, defined inside the `h()` function, is not visible inside the `g()` function, because the latter is a different *scope* than the former.  If you want to make your code work, consider the following suggestion:

```
g <- function(input) {
    get(input)
}

h <- function(input) {
    g(input)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First the answer to "why:

When R searches for a variable, it searches the local environment and then starts going up the chain of parents. Here, g and h are both in the global environment. g will search its local environment and won't find the variable "input", then it will search the global environment and won't find it there either.

Now the answer to "but I want to... just because":

We just have to tell get() where to look, which is in the environment of the *calling* function (i.e., h's local environment):

```
> g <- function() {
    get("input", pos = parent.frame(1))
}

h <- function(input){
    g()
}

h(1:3)
[1] 1 2 3
```

Legal disclaimer: If you use functions like this in practice, I suggest you buy some foot insurance.